# Write to TextView overlays previous write

Tags: objective-c

I have a TextView created in IB... I have two "paragraphs" I want to write, which appear to work, with the exception of the 2nd write overlays the first.

How do I fix this?

First write:

```
resultText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decode Data:  %@, \n%@\n\n",symbol.data, symbol.typeName];  //  display it...
```

2nd write:

```
    resultText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nDatabase: \n%@ \n%@ \n%@", 
        [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)],
        [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)],
        [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)]];
```

Comment: So your problem is that the "Database..." string is overwriting the "Decode data..." string? Also, is this a UITextView you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're just assigning the text twice, instead of appending.  An easy way to fix that would be to change your 2nd write to:

```
resultText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nDatabase: \n%@ \n%@ \n%@", 
    resultText.text,
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)],
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)],
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)]];
```

That will keep the previous text you had there.

EDIT:

```
resultText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decode Data:  %@, %@",symbol.data, symbol.typeName];

resultText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nDatabase: %@, %@, %@", 
    resultText.text,
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)],
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)],
    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)]];
```

Comment: Dan... it splits the text, giving the title of text2 before the data for text1, followed by the data for text2.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the text is and how you want it displayed?  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Decode Data: field1, field2, field3

Database: field4, field5, field6

Comment: I'm really not sure what's wrong with this, other than formatting, all of your text should be there.  I guess I still don't quite understand how you want it to show up

Comment: Decode Data: symbol.data  symbol.typeName
\n
Database: compiledStmt0  compiledStmt1  compiledStmt2

Comment: If you don't want newlines between the tokens, then don't use newlines, see my editted code